# Hide view-source in core php or html

Tags: php, html

How do I hide view-source in core php or html?

I have read this but I am unable to understand how to use:

[Web Developer Class: How to Hide your Source Code](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/article.php/3875651/Web-Developer-Class-How-to-Hide-your-Source-Code.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer: You can't hide your HTML source code from anyone who is willing to spend more than 15 seconds looking for it. Don't bother trying.

Your PHP code, however, never leaves the server, so that will stay hidden.

Comment: But most of the site i am unable to see view source code. link given below:
http://www.htmlguardian.org/help_main.html

Comment: On most of your site or just most websites on the internet? I have rarely encountered a site that hides its HTML code... It's really pointless trying to hide it as anyone with any web development knowledge at all will be able to see it. Just go to a page which uses the method you linked with Chrome, for example. Right click the page and choose 'Inspect Element'. Protection defeated!

Comment: You didn't click 'view frame source' @joy. It is all readily available.

Answer (score 2):

If it's about HTML - you can't.

Also, the article you're citing is unfortunately misleading. Even if you manage to "uglify" your page source, client's browser will parse it anyway and will print it in a prettified form when using "View Source".

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible to hide the source code by sending a "Link" header to the browser, similar to the `<link .../>` tags you would include in the HTML head section. This can be used to include a css, or even an html import into the DOM without sending anything in the body of the response from the server. [Here's an example](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/css-without-html).

The header would look something like this:

```
Link: <some-file.html>; rel=import
```

> In the same way that the HTML `<LINK>` element expresses a link between the document it occurs in and some other resource in the web, a Link: entity header expresses a link between the entity it occurs in and some other resource in the web.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/9707-link-header.html

Note that this only hides the "view-source" contents, but the developer tools included with the browser will still show what had been parsed.

Comment: Nice answer - I had no idea that Link could be used for that. I'd accept this over my own. :)

Comment: @jsa pretty nuts, I learned about it from a JSConf video a while back, here's the link, @ around 14:50 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPL-mA77bDo